# One Plus 5 does not appears in ADB

Tags: adb, usb, usb-debugging, 9.0-pie

I wish to install an another OS on my OnePlus 5 phone. At least try...

So I follow the various guides on the web, valid developer options, click on "unlock OEM" and "USB debugging". OK. I also install adb as well as android udev rules on my linux desktop. The phone itself is on android 9.

Then when I plug in a USB cable (from the manufacturer), I can get some notifications in dmesg only. Not in lsusb.

So far I can see (in dmesg) the phone plugged in usb only when it's on usb tethering.

And I can never see it in the adb devices list. Nor can I see any prompt on the phone asking me to validate my computer RSA fingerprint.

Someone got a suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

Just bought a brand new cable. Phone is recognized by the computer and install' is done in the minute.